# I'm getting an error while sorting an array with the following code

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I am able to get output for this:

```
int arr[][]={{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{1,3}};
Arrays.sort(arr,(a,b)->(b[0]-a[0]));
```

But it's showing error for this:

```
int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
Arrays.sort(arr,(a,b)->(b-a));
```

```
Error:     method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no variant of `Arrays.sort()` that accepts an `int[]` and a `Comparator`, which is not surprising, given that you cannot define a `Comparator<int>` (generic type parameters must be reference types).

If you change your array to `Integer[]`, it will work:

```
Integer[] arr={1,2,3,4,5,6};
Arrays.sort(arr,(a,b)->(b-a));
```

Your first snippet works because the element type of your first (2D) array is `int[]` (array of `int`s), and arrays are reference types. Therefore it fits the signature of the `public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` method.